# Display the ows_modified crawl property using SP.DateTimeUtil.SPRelativeDateTime.getRelativeDateTimeString will show wrong dates in display template

Tags: 2013, development, display-template, search-results-webpart

I am working on an on-premises sharepoint 2013. and i want to show the modified date for my documents inside a Search Result web-part. so seems there is not any built-in managed property for this. so i created a new managed property and i associate it with the `ows_modified` crawl property as follow:-

[image]

then i add the `RefinableDate00` it to my Search result web part where i got values such as for my current 2 items:-

- `15/09/2017 15:24:00`
- `21/09/2017 17:15:20`

which are the exact modified date/time. but usually for my dates field inside my Display templates such as `created` and `lastmodifiedtime` i show them in a user-friendly way using the following code:-

```
 _#= SP.DateTimeUtil.SPRelativeDateTime.getRelativeDateTimeString(new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.Created), true , SP.DateTimeUtil.SPCalendarType.none, false ) =#_
```

which should show the date in format such as; "2 minutes ago", "in an hour", "Testerday 12:20", etc..

but when i tried to use this function for my `RefinableDate00`, as follow:-

```
_#= SP.DateTimeUtil.SPRelativeDateTime.getRelativeDateTimeString(new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.Created), true , SP.DateTimeUtil.SPCalendarType.none, false ) =#
```

i got weird results, where the Date will be in `2018`, as follow:-

- i got `09 March, 2018` instead of `15/09/2017 15:24:00`
- i got `09 September, 2018` instead of `2 minute ago`

so can anyone adivce what could be causing this problem?